# Accessing Flickr API in CLI

Tags: php, authentication, flickr

I am using [phpfickr](https://github.com/dan-coulter/phpflickr) and need to run it in CLI.

But when executing `$ php getToken.php`, but I'm not being able to getting authenticated. I have the `$app_id` and `$secret`.

Please, I am new to this and haven't found a correct solution.

Comment: Did you correctly replace `<api key>` and `<secret>` in `getToken.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on issue https://github.com/dan-coulter/phpflickr/issues/48 , adding

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

got me going.

This issue appears to be merged into master branch, but it does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

The [phpFlickr library](https://github.com/dan-coulter/phpflickr) you've linked to is very old.

- Its most recent commit was on July 7, 2014, roughly 2.5 years ago.
- It uses PHP 4 style constructors (named after the class), which have been [deprecated in PHP 7 and will be removed in a future version of PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php).
- It uses `var` keywords, another PHP 4 anachronism, which were briefly deprecated but then brought back [as a semi-synonym of `public`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

If you *really* want to use this library it should be as simple as

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/phpflickr/phpFlickr.php';

// Make sure to fill in your API key and secret!
$flickr = new phpFlickr('your-api-key-goes-here', 'your-api-secret-goes-here');
```

The `getToken.php` file that you referenced does this. Perhaps you forgot to fill in your API key and secret?

Once you have your `$flickr` object you can use it to interact with Flickr's API. For example, you can do something like this to see titles of recently-posted public photos:

```
foreach ($flickr->photos_getRecent()['photos']['photo'] as $photo) {
    echo $photo['title'] . "\n";
}
```

However, there are more modern options. [`rezzza/flickr`](https://packagist.org/packages/rezzza/flickr), for example, is available on Packagist and has over 16K installs. It uses modern PHP features like namespaces, `__construct()` constructors, and visibility keywords. It also seems to have a more sane API, though that's subject to opinion.

If you are already using Composer you should be able to `composer require rezzza/flickr`, then proceed as its README suggests. If you're not using Composer, [start](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md). It is an important part of the modern PHP ecosystem.

Comment: The earlier library did work; the ssl did not appear to be present in master, although it was merged.

Comment: @maan81, it worked for me without any changes. Are you sure you were working with the latest version of the code?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I am using https://github.com/dan-coulter/phpflickr/blob/master/phpFlickr.php, and this is what I got https://s29.postimg.org/aericl6xj/phpflickr_php_Flickr_php_at_master_dan_coulter.png